# Insert content of file after first pattern match using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need to find first occurrence of "all.css" and insert content of my file below this occurrence. Code that I use in my bash-script:

```
FILE="$OLD_WEB_SOURCES/logon.html"
BLA="$DIR/first_insert_android" 
sed '/all.css/ r $BLA' "$FILE" > TMP1
mv TMP1 "$FILE"
```

But this code doesnt work for me. BTW `echo` of variables FILE and BLA shows correct path. Can  someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "But this code doesnt work for me". How exactly?

Comment: @LutzHorn, "find first occurrence of "all.css" and insert content of my file below this occurrence"

Comment: try with double quote in sed ($BLA is not interpreted with simple quote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes( `"` ) to access the shell variable( $BLA ) in `sed`.
Try this,

```
sed "/all.css/ r $BLA" "$FILE" > TMP1
```

Comment: Haha, it works! Thank you. I will able to accept your answer in 10 minutes.